# Mysql Order By(sorting data) opposite gender first then same gender etc

Tags: mysql

I want to sort users data according to multiple column's like
 1. opposite gender then same gender
 2. same city
 3. same interest

Comment: Are you actually after a matching algorithm?

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes I think so i make a mysql query for it and now its working fine
select * from table where status=1
ORDER BY gender = '".$gender."' DESC, city = '".$udata['city']."' DESC, total_rcv_kisses DESC, interest IN ('".$udata['interest']."') ASC, age ASC limit ".$limit.",".$start;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from table where status=1 ORDER BY gender = '".$gender."' DESC, city = '".$udata['city']."' DESC, total_rcv_kisses DESC, interest IN ('".$udata['interest']."') ASC, age ASC limit ".$limit.",".$start;